# Using a parameter with a Javascript object?

Tags: javascript

Currently I can do:

```
function addStat() {
player.str = player.str + 1;
}
```

But I want to be able to use things other than just "str" with my player object. So I decided with doing something like this:

```
function addStat(stat) {
player.stat = player.stat + 1;
}
```

But that doesn't seem to work, iv'e tried looking up the syntax for using parameters but could not find anything similar to the way I need.

I learned about "this" but I can't get it to work with my function.

I thought this:

```
function addStat(thing, stat) {
thing.stat = thing.stat + 1;
statReset();
}
```

would work but I can see why it won't. I made sure the rest of my javascript and html work and when I add those functions nothing breaks, it just doesn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically access object property using variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When assigning properties with a variable, you need to use **bracket notation**, as opposed to dot notation. This, then, looks like:

```
function addStat(stat) {
    (stat in player) ? ++player[stat] : player[stat] = 1;
}
```

Due to comments (that I disagree with), I figured I should mention that since you are attempting to modify a property that may not exist, you should also add a safety check to see if you can modify it.

Otherwise you will be modifying `undefined`, and that will cause undesired output..

Comment: @Andy -- while your comment is valid, it has nothing to do with the current question at hand.

Comment: @Jamiec it works for _setting_ new properties, it doesn't work for _modifying_ properties that don't yet exist.

Comment: @Alnitak - How can you *modify* something that doesnt exist?

Comment: Do I need to make the object with that notation also?

Currently I have it like:

obj {
     obj.value = x
}

Comment: @Jamiec _exactly!_.    A simple work around is `player[stat] = (player[stat] + 1)  || 1`

Comment: Guys, as I said, while the comment is valid, it has nothing to do with the current question. The concern was about the syntax.

Comment: @RomanP no, you can't use variables as keys in "object literal" syntax

Comment: @NickDugger, I disagree. The OP is moving from using specific keys to possibly passing in a parameter for a key that doesn't yet exist. I think that's worth mentioning.

Comment: @Andy while I entirely disagree, I've modified the post to reflect this discussion.

Comment: @NickDugger, if you disagree with it you shouldn't add it to your answer. That's just weird, man.

Answer (score 0):

You can access properties with []:

```
function addStat(prop) {
    player[prop] = player[prop] + 1;
}
```

so calling `addStat("stat")` will actually set `player.stat`.

Comment: No, it will add 1 to player.stat on the assumption that the key exists.

Comment: OP post also assumes this. There is no checking in original code.

Comment: The OP doesn't assume this because he might decide to pass in a parameter for a keys that doesn't exist yet. I think that's worth mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, the syntax

```
object.key
```

is equivalent to

```
object["key"]
```

So your `thing.stat` is equivalent to `thing["stat"]`, i.e. the key is the literal string `"stat"` when what you really want is to use the value referenced by the parameter `stat` as the key:

```
thing[stat] = thing[stat] + 1;
```